# Move data from one cloud instance to another

Tags: cloud

I have a 4GB file in one cloud instance (dev server). I have to move this file to another cloud instance (test server). how can I accomplish this.

Comment: You don't include enough info in your question for anyone to give you a good answer.  Which cloud?  How did the file get there in the first place?  What access, if any, do you have to these instances?  Is FTP an option?  File copy?  There's an excellent [blog post on how to ask good questions](http://whathaveyoutried.com) that you may find useful.

Comment: @DanPichelman thank you for the suggestion dan. I am very new to using cloud environment. I have both the instances set up on amazon cloud. I have admin access to both the servers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use scp to move the file from dev server to the test server.

On dev server run the command

```
scp -i testkey.pem my4gbfile username@hostname:
```

where teskey.pem is the ec2 pem file that you will need to copy to a location on the dev server.
my4gbfile is the file you want to move.
username is the username on the test server, its usually ubuntu if the test ec2 instance has ubuntu linux.
hostname is the ip or hostname of the test server ec2 instance.